# Conceiving a wind turbine as a thermodynamic machine

Tags: fluid-mechanics, thermodynamics, wind-power

Traditionally, and continuing till the present day, wind turbines are conceived/presented as power plants which harvest the (macroscopic) kinetic energy carried by an externally available airflow, with corresponding [upper bounds on how much can be harvested](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betz%27s_law). Implicitly, this amounts on or relies on an assumption that it would be generally impossible to harvest the internal energy in the flowing gas by allowing it to exert [expansion work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_(thermodynamics)) onto our system (in contrast to this being possible in steam turbines). Naive calculations, with airflow-parameters (speed, temperature, pressure) typical for our terrestrial atmosphere, suggest that one should be able able to harvest much more energy in this way than merely a fraction of the airflow's kinetic energy.

**Q: What, if anything, prevents us from building wind-turbines that significantly exploit "expansion work"?**

Comment: I've read it twice but I'm still don't understand what you are asking. Can you edit to ask a straight technical question?

Comment: @Transistor: I've slightly edited the question in bold, but that's unfortunately all I can do; the question is on the interface between theoretical physics and engineering so it comes inherently with a broad scope, at the cost of not being "technically straighforward".

Comment: Expansion work requires a difference in pressure across the system. Where is this going to come from?

Comment: From the physical obstruction provided by the wind turbine itself (or other objects in the surrounding landscape)?

Comment: Check out the Betz lmit...

Comment: What are your calculations that show this can be done?  To paraphrase @Transistor, what are you going to expand that air **into**?

Comment: A heat engine compresses the working fluid using heat energy, and then allows it to expand and do mechanical work. A wind turbine does not have any external heat input. Increasing the "inlet pressure" on a wind turbine by reducing the velocity simply reduces the mass flow through the turbine.

Comment: I echo the comments requesting your math that this should be doable. draw a diagram for the termodynamic cycle, it will be intructive.